# how to do time stamping in access db using c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection();
mycon.ConnectionString =@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Dinesh\C#\GIS_Power\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Power_DB1.accdb";
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Emp_ID,Asset_ID)VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
    mycon.Open();
    command.Connection = mycon;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    mycon.Close();
}
```

this is the code that I have written to insert some details in my access db. I want that this button click also add the date and time of click into a column in my db. I tried to directly add a function GetDate within INSERT but it failed to execute. Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. You shouldn't be passing TextBox.Text directly to a query.  Use Parameters to guard against data injection. 2.  Why can't you just use `DateTime.Now` and update your insert query?

Comment: you did the right thing using `GetDate` , what you need to do is show the error that you got and we can help you fix it

Comment: @Harrison - using `DateTime.Now` may be a problem if you have several servers with different clocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this code, but it should get you started...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection()
    {
        mycon.ConnectionString =@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Dinesh\C#\GIS_Power\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Power_DB1.accdb";

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Emp_ID, Asset_ID, Date_Column) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        command.Parameters.Add("@EmpID", OleDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = textBox1.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@AssetID", OleDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = textBox2.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Timestamp", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;

        command.Connection = mycon;
        mycon.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: still not working. what value do i give for date in insert query? coz the other two are taking textbox values but what about date?

Comment: @user3219362 I was using `DateTime.Now`.  Based on your situation, you may want to use the UTC time?  What error are you getting?

Comment: Data type mismatch in criteria expression. i used DateTime.Now too

Comment: @user3219362 Use `OleDbType.Date`.

Comment: @user3219362 I changed the OleDbType to Date. Gord was making the comment as I was updating the answer ;-)

Comment: still same problem. command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Emp_ID,Asset_ID, Actual_C)VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "',OleDbType.Date)";

Comment: @user3219362 What you wrote isn't my answer. If you weren't going to use parameters then you would use DateTime.Now.  But the `?` were intentional to use verbatim and fill in with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Add datetime column with default value of now

It can be done like the below

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_YourTable DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR YourColumn
```

Comment: will i have to write another command.CommandText statement? where do i add your line in my code? Cause if i add it, too many errors popping up

Comment: The Access Database Engine says "Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause."