# Recording time/date from C# windows application form is inserted into access database?

Tags: c#, date, ms-access, time

I have developed one c# basic form, when i click submit the data is getting populated in database, But i also want that time & date also get populated in database once the user will click the form, so as to know when he submitted this form.

Can somebody Help.!!

Below is source code of whatever i have done till now.

```
namespace testing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


           OleDbConnection cnon = new OleDbConnection();
       cnon.ConnectionString =@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\visual_c\Database71.accdb";
       OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
       command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO electricity (Asset_name,Asset_number,Emp_id) VALUES (@Asset_name, @Asset_number,@Emp_id)";
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assetname", textBox1.Text);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assetnumber", textBox2.Text);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_id", textBox3.Text);
       cnon.Open();
       command.Connection = cnon;
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       cnon.Close();

    }        
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to do time stamping in access db using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292262/how-to-do-time-stamping-in-access-db-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

```
   INSERT INTO electricity (Asset_name,Asset_number,Emp_id,timestamp) 
   VALUES (@Asset_name, @Asset_number,@Emp_id,now())
```

**Or better**, just set the default value of the timestamp field to Now() in the table, so there is no need to worry.

[image: add timestamp]

Comment: Changing the table in Access is probably the best solution

Comment: command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO electricity (Asset_name,Asset_number,Emp_id,Timestamp) VALUES (@Asset_name, @Asset_number,@Emp_id,now())";   this is my statement and unfortunately its not working

Comment: Please get rid of timestamp, you should be going with option 2, see the picture above. Your sql is `INSERT INTO electricity (Asset_name,Asset_number,Emp_id) VALUES (@Asset_name, @Asset_number,@Emp_id)"`

Comment: @Remou-- I have set the validation rule in access database timestamp column to now. but it does not populate date and white when fields are entered in Db through C# form

Answer (score 1):

Your best is to declare a new field in electricity and set its default value to =now()
You don't need to modify your code.

Comment: can you please explain somewat more

Comment: if you have these fields in electricity: Asset_name,Asset_number,Emp_id,timestamp
with timestamp default value now()
but you execute this insert: 
INSERT INTO electricity (Asset_name,Asset_number,Emp_id) 
VALUES (@Asset_name, @Asset_number,@Emp_id)
timestamp field will take the current date/time at the moment of the insert

Comment: I did similarly like that but that form gives new error!! as when i click submit button after entering fileds of asset name, asset number, emp id, it gives error of syntax error in insert into statement , OleDb connection was unhandled